# JPA always fails to create (H2) database schema and tables when using DDL scripts

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, h2, persistence.xml

I'm using JPA on a standard Java project. I have a `persistence.xml` deployment descriptor that looks like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_2.xsd"
    version="2.2">
  <persistence-unit name="test" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <class>...</class>

    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.h2.Driver" />
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="" />
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:h2:mem:java_design_patterns;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;MODE=PostgreSQL;" />
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="sa" />
      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.create-script-source" value="database/schema.h2.sql" />
      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create" />
      <property name="javax.persistence.sql-load-script-source" value="database/data.sql" />

      <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
      <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

The script `schema.h2.sql` contains:

```sql
---
--- CREATE TABLE STATEMENT(S)
---
create table spell_books (
  id         uuid,
  name       varchar(150) not null,
  updated_at timestamp    not null default current_timestamp(),
  version    integer      not null
);

create table spells (
  id            uuid,
  name          varchar(150) not null,
  updated_at    timestamp    not null default current_timestamp(),
  version       integer      not null,

  spell_book_id uuid
);

create table wizards (
  id         uuid,
  name       varchar(150) not null,
  updated_at timestamp    not null default current_timestamp(),
  version    integer      not null
);

create table wizards_spell_books (
  spell_book_id uuid      not null,
  wizard_id     uuid      not null,
  updated_at    timestamp not null default current_timestamp()
);


---
--- ALTER TABLE STATEMENT(S)
---
alter table spell_books add primary key (id);

alter table spells add primary key (id);
alter table spells add foreign key (spell_book_id) references spell_books (id);

alter table wizards add primary key (id);

alter table wizards_spell_books add foreign key (spell_book_id) references spell_books (id);
alter table wizards_spell_books add foreign key (wizard_id) references wizards (id);
```

With this configuration, I'm expecting that any time I run my tests JPA should be able to generate the schema (and populate the data, only used by the tests), but so far I'm always getting errors like these:

```bash
03-08-2021 20:22:33,414 |-  WARN in org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl:72 [main] - HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
03-08-2021 20:22:34,001 |-  WARN in org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl:27 [main] - GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "
    create table spell_books (
       " via JDBC Statement
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "
    create table spell_books (
       " via JDBC Statement
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.28.Final.jar:5.4.28.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.applySqlString(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:439) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.28.Final.jar:5.4.28.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.createFromScript(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:192) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.28.Final.jar:5.4.28.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.performCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:162) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.28.Final.jar:5.4.28.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.doCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:135) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.28.Final.jar:5.4.28.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.doCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:121) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.28.Final.jar:5.4.28.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:156) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.28.Final.jar:5.4.28.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:73) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.28.Final.jar:5.4.28.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:318) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.28.Final.jar:5.4.28.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:468) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.28.Final.jar:5.4.28.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1259) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.28.Final.jar:5.4.28.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:56) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.28.Final.jar:5.4.28.Final]
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:79) ~[javax.persistence-api-2.2.jar:2.2]
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54) ~[javax.persistence-api-2.2.jar:2.2]
    at org.acme.service_layer.support.EntityManagerProducer.entityManagerFactory(EntityManagerProducer.java:23) ~[classes/:?]
    at org.acme.service_layer.support.EntityManagerProducer.getEntityManager(EntityManagerProducer.java:29) ~[classes/:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.StaticMethodInjectionPoint.invoke(StaticMethodInjectionPoint.java:95) ~[weld-se-shaded-4.0.0.Final.jar:4.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.StaticMethodInjectionPoint.invoke(StaticMethodInjectionPoint.java:85) ~[weld-se-shaded-4.0.0.Final.jar:4.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.ProducerMethodProducer.produce(ProducerMethodProducer.java:103) ~[weld-se-shaded-4.0.0.Final.jar:4.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.AbstractMemberProducer.produce(AbstractMemberProducer.java:161) ~[weld-se-shaded-4.0.0.Final.jar:4.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.AbstractProducerBean.create(AbstractProducerBean.java:180) ~[weld-se-shaded-4.0.0.Final.jar:4.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.weld.junit.ContextImpl.get(ContextImpl.java:69) ~[weld-junit-common-3.0.0.Final.jar:3.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstanceStrategy$DefaultContextualInstanceStrategy.get(ContextualInstanceStrategy.java:100) ~[weld-se-shaded-4.0.0.Final.jar:4.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstanceStrategy$CachingContextualInstanceStrategy.get(ContextualInstanceStrategy.java:177) ~[weld-se-shaded-4.0.0.Final.jar:4.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstance.get(ContextualInstance.java:50) ~[weld-se-shaded-4.0.0.Final.jar:4.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ContextBeanInstance.getInstance(ContextBeanInstance.java:102) ~[weld-se-shaded-4.0.0.Final.jar:4.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:105) ~[weld-se-shaded-4.0.0.Final.jar:4.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.weldx.persistence.EntityManager$1053374383$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.getCriteriaBuilder(Unknown Source) ~[weld-se-shaded-4.0.0.Final.jar:?]
    at org.acme.service_layer.persistence.SpellBookDao.findByName(SpellBookDao.java:19) ~[classes/:?]
    at org.acme.service_layer.persistence.SpellBookDaoTest.create(SpellBookDaoTest.java:37) ~[classes/:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:628) ~[junit-platform-commons-1.4.1.jar:1.4.1]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:117) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.4.1.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:184) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.4.1.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.4.1.jar:1.4.1]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:180) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.4.1.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:127) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.4.1.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:68) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.4.1.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:135) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.4.1.jar:1.4.1]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.4.1.jar:1.4.1]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.4.1.jar:1.4.1]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.4.1.jar:1.4.1]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.4.1.jar:1.4.1]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.4.1.jar:1.4.1]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.4.1.jar:1.4.1]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.4.1.jar:1.4.1]
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541) ~[?:?]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.4.1.jar:1.4.1]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.4.1.jar:1.4.1]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.4.1.jar:1.4.1]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.4.1.jar:1.4.1]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.4.1.jar:1.4.1]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.4.1.jar:1.4.1]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.4.1.jar:1.4.1]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.4.1.jar:1.4.1]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.4.1.jar:1.4.1]
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541) ~[?:?]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.4.1.jar:1.4.1]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.4.1.jar:1.4.1]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.4.1.jar:1.4.1]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.4.1.jar:1.4.1]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.4.1.jar:1.4.1]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.4.1.jar:1.4.1]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.4.1.jar:1.4.1]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.4.1.jar:1.4.1]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.4.1.jar:1.4.1]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.4.1.jar:1.4.1]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.4.1.jar:1.4.1]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.4.1.jar:1.4.1]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:229) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.4.1.jar:1.4.1]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:197) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.4.1.jar:1.4.1]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:211) [junit-platform-launcher-1.4.1.jar:1.4.1]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:191) [junit-platform-launcher-1.4.1.jar:1.4.1]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:128) [junit-platform-launcher-1.4.1.jar:1.4.1]
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71) [junit5-rt.jar:?]
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33) [junit-rt.jar:?]
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:220) [junit-rt.jar:?]
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:53) [junit-rt.jar:?]
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error in SQL statement "
    CREATE TABLE SPELL_BOOKS (
       [*]"; expected "identifier"; SQL statement:

    create table spell_books (
        [42001-200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:453) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:429) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getSyntaxError(DbException.java:243) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readColumnIdentifier(Parser.java:4976) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseTableColumnDefinition(Parser.java:8437) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseCreateTable(Parser.java:8379) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseCreate(Parser.java:6276) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:903) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:843) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:815) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:738) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:657) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:595) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1235) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.executeInternal(JdbcStatement.java:212) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.execute(JdbcStatement.java:201) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.28.Final.jar:5.4.28.Final]
    ... 84 more
03-08-2021 20:22:34,160 |-  WARN in org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper:137 [main] - SQL Error: 42102, SQLState: 42S02
03-08-2021 20:22:34,161 |- ERROR in org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper:142 [main] - Table "SPELL_BOOKS" not found; SQL statement:
select spellbook0_.id as id1_0_, spellbook0_.version as version2_0_, spellbook0_.name as name3_0_ from spell_books spellbook0_ where spellbook0_.name=? [42102-200]

javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement

    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:154)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1602)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.getSingleResult(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1641)
    at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getSingleResult(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:111)
    at org.acme.service_layer.persistence.SpellBookDao.findByName(SpellBookDao.java:24)
    at org.acme.service_layer.persistence.SpellBookDaoTest.create(SpellBookDaoTest.java:37)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:628)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:117)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:184)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:180)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:127)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:68)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:229)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:197)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:211)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:191)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:128)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:220)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:53)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:186)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:151)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:2103)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2040)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2018)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:948)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:349)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2849)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2831)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2663)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2658)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:506)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:400)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:219)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1414)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1625)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1593)
    ... 55 more
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "SPELL_BOOKS" not found; SQL statement:
select spellbook0_.id as id1_0_, spellbook0_.version as version2_0_, spellbook0_.name as name3_0_ from spell_books spellbook0_ where spellbook0_.name=? [42102-200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:453)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:429)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:205)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:181)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableOrView(Parser.java:7628)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableFilter(Parser.java:1970)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectFromPart(Parser.java:2827)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelect(Parser.java:2959)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseQuerySub(Parser.java:2817)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectUnion(Parser.java:2649)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseQuery(Parser.java:2620)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:868)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:843)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:815)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:738)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:657)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:595)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1235)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.<init>(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:76)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareStatement(JdbcConnection.java:352)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:149)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:176)
    ... 71 more
```

I can't tell what's wrong with the DDL script(s).

Can someone point me to what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: there is no `integer`  data type instead, use `int`
http://www.h2database.com/html/datatypes.html#int_type

Comment: I understand, but somehow the `integer` type works, not sure if it's because I have `MODE=PostgreSQL;`. Anyway, the issue is with the file format: statements must be placed on a single line (each). Somehow looks like the parser doesn't understand new lines, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow I find this insane. The problem was that each statement must be on its own line. For instance, this wouldn't work:

```sql
create table spell_books (
  id         uuid,
  name       varchar(150) not null,
  updated_at timestamp    not null default current_timestamp(),
  version    integer      not null
);
```

...but this works:

```sql
create table spell_books (id uuid, name varchar(150) not null, updated_at timestamp not null default current_timestamp(), version integer not null);
```